# Spring MVC 4 + JSP + JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jsp, jdbc

I'm using Spring MVC 4, JSP and MySQL to display data in a simple request.

- **Database Name :** contactdb
  **Table Name       :** contact
  [image]
- Records
  [image]
- My Folder Structure
  [image]
- I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml file:
  ---> mysql-connector-java-5.1.30
  ---> spring-jdbc-4.1.6
- **com.rh.model/Contact.java**

  ```
  public class Contact {
      private int id;
      private String name;
      private String email;
      private String address;
      private String telephone;

      //constructors
      //getters and setters
  }
  ```
- **com.rh.dao/ContactDAO.java**

  ```
  public interface ContactDAO {
      public List<Contact> getAll();
  }
  ```
- **com.rh.dao/ContactDAOImpl.java**

  ```
  public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO{
      private DataSource dataSource;

      public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
      }

      public List<Contact> getAll() {
          String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM contact";
          List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
          Connection conn = null;
          PreparedStatement ps = null;
          ResultSet rs = null;

          try{
              conn = dataSource.getConnection();
              ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);
              rs = ps.executeQuery();

              while(rs.next()){
                  Contact contact = new Contact();
                  contact.setId(rs.getInt("contact_id"));
                  contact.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                  contact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                  contact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                  contact.setTelephone(rs.getString("telephone"));
                  contactList.add(contact);
              }
              rs.close();
              ps.close();
              conn.close();
         }catch(SQLException e){
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
      return contactList;
  }
  ```
- **com.rh.config/Spring.xml**

  ```
  <bean id="contactDAO" class="com.rh.dao.ContactDAOImpl">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contactdb" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>
  ```
- **com.rh.controller/Test1Controller.java**

  ```
  @Controller
  public class Test1Controller {

  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com.rh.config/Spring.xml");

  ContactDAO contactDAO = ctx.getBean("contactDAO", ContactDAO.class);

  @RequestMapping(value="/")
  public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
      List<Contact> listContract = contactDAO.getAll();
      model.addObject("listContact", listContract);
      return model;
  }
  ```

  }
- **index.jsp**

  ```
  ...
  <c:forEach var="contact" items="${listContact}" varStatus="status">
      <tr>
          <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
          <td>${contact.name}</td>
          <td>${contact.email}</td>
          <td>${contact.address}</td>
          <td>${contact.telephone}</td>      
      </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  ```
- However, from above code, I can't get the database value. 
    [image]
- Which part am I writing wrong?

Comment: What is the URL in the address bar of your browser? What happens when adding a breakpoint in the controller and executing everything step by step? Why don't you use a JdbcTemplate, since you want to use Spring JDBC? That would deal with proper closing of resources, which your code doesn't.

Comment: The URl is localhost:8080/Test1/

Comment: If I want to use JdbcTemplate, what dependencies should I included?

Comment: None. It's in spring-jdbc, that you already included. What happens when adding a breakpoint in the controller and executing everything step by step?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing from what I can see which is obviously wrong. As the comments suggest, I would use a debugger to see what the values are in the DAO, and in the Controller, at each step of the journey.

Pure speculation, but I notice you have a minor typo for a variable name `listContract` in the Controller:

```
List<Contact> listContract = contactDAO.getAll();
```

It shouldn't affect the code working in this example, but maybe just double-check for typos in other areas of the code?